# mapbox android. Как подставить свой локальный тайл?

Tags: android, tile, mapbox

Я использую mapbox в моём андроид-приложении.Мне нужно,что бы пользователь мог пользоваться картой оффлайн. Но кеширование карты спомощью Mapbox offlineManager скачивает слишком большой объем карты (примерно 56МБ). Поэтому было решено попробовать подставлять свои растровые тайлы в карту. Но тут я столкнулся с проблемой. В google maps и OSM это делается легко, а в mapbox не получается. Документация ограниченая, а примеров почти нет. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Знает кто-нибудь как подставить свой локальный тайл в карту Mapbox?

Answer (score 0):

Офф-лайн тайлы для Android необходимо генерировать. В соответствии со стилем и данными, которые вы хотите отобразить на карте. У MapBox есть свой генератор, он описан в документации, хотя имеет некоторые ограничения.